# MySQL select from multiple tables, keep all columns and row without match

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by, union

I have 2 tables

`tableA`:

| id | dateA | colA | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-11 12:00:00 | A |  |
| 2 | 2022-11-12 12:00:00 | B |  |
| 3 | 2022-11-14 12:00:00 | C |  |

`tableB`:

| id | dateB | colB | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-11-05 12:00:00 | D |  |
| 4 | 2022-11-06 12:00:00 | E |  |
| 5 | 2022-11-13 12:00:00 | F |  |

and I want put all rows to one result and sort it by column `date`

Wanted result (rows from both tables sorted by column `date DESC`):

| id | date | colA | colB | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-11-14 12:00:00 | C |  |  |  |
| 5 | 2022-11-13 12:00:00 |  | F |  |  |
| 2 | 2022-11-12 12:00:00 | B |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2022-11-11 12:00:00 | A |  |  |  |
| 4 | 2022-11-06 12:00:00 |  | E |  |  |
| 3 | 2022-11-05 12:00:00 |  | D |  |  |

I can combine tables, but tables are "squashed"...

```sql
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.id, b.id) AS id, 
    COALESCE(a.dateA, b.dateB) AS date, 
    a.colA, 
    b.colB
FROM tableA AS a, tableB AS b
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` and `ORDER BY`. This requires enumerating the columns:

```
select id, dateA as dateX, colA, null as colB from tableA
union all
select id, dateB, null, colB from tableB
order by dateX
```

`union all` combines two datasets. Since we have different columns in the two tables, we need to arrange both `select` clauses so that they return the same set of columns ; `null` values can be used to fill in "missing" columns in a given dataset.

As for sorting the resultset : in MySQL, a single `ORDER BY` in a `UNION ALL` query applies to the whole resultset (*after* it was unioned). The query just does that (using `dateX`, the column alias that was created in the subqueries).

Comment: oooh, I see now.
and is this correct too?
```sql
SELECT id, dateA, colA, null FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT id, dateB, null, colB FROM tableB
ORDER BY dateTime DESC
```
the result seems ok, but is it really ok?

Comment: @Ondra: column aliases are important, and must be consistent between the (first) `select` and the `order by` clause, as shown in my query.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to show the rows that share same `id` and `date` as one row, you can build on top of GMB's answer:

```
select id, dateX as date, max(colA) as colA, max(colB) as colB
from (
  select id, dateA as dateX, colA, null as colB from tableA
  union all
  select id, dateB, null, colB from tableB
) as q
group by id, dateX
order by dateX
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aovPepnoy6wh8Suxq56M4v/0)